# Linux:How to pass command line argument to an command line argument that is being passed to a script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have two scripts say **script1.py** and **script2.sh**.

script1.py takes as command line argument say "-t somethinng" and script2.sh takes script1.py as its command line argument say : **script2.sh -class script1.py** .

I can execute script1.py as standalone script by: ***"script1.py -t value"*** .

Now what I want to do is to pass command lines to script1.py at the same time when I am passing script1.py to script2.sh as command line argument.

I want to try something like this-

**script2.sh  --class script1:MyClass"-t value" --verbose**

script2.sh is all set up to get Myclass from --class argument.
Now above command is what i want to do .
// where MyClass is a class in script1.py

Answer (score 1):

Are `script2.sh` and `script1.py` your code or somebody else's?

If they are yours (or at least `script2.sh`), you can implement such feature yourself (using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) or equivalent); if not, well there's no built in way to do that, as in: what you're asking has nothing to do with the generic Bash/shell functionality of passing arguments.

P.S. Or what @hek2mgl said might also just work.

Comment: These files are in SVN.                                                                                         
In order to edit these two files I have to post Code Review of these two files and
 that takes time to get approval and then go to next stage.
 
 
script2.sh  --class script1:MyClass"-t value" --verbose

script2.sh is all set up to get Myclass from --class argument.
Now above command is what i want to do .
// where MyClass is a class in script1.py

Comment: hek2mgl's is not working for me. Also that is a standard solution.

Answer (score 1):

Brackets cannot being used here. The simplest and most common way would be to pass the whole python sub command-line as a string:

```
script2.sh -class "script1.py -t value" --verbose
```

Comment: script2.sh  --class script1:MyClass"-t value" --verbose

script2.sh is all set up to get Myclass from --class argument.
Now above command is what i want to do .
// where MyClass is a class in script1.py